# How do I expand \pgfkeys properly?

Tags: expansion, pgfkeys

I am using `pgfkeys` to hold formatting parameters. The tree is set up with a set of default values, as well as customizations for various formats. Those formats each have a basic definition, which in turn can have multiple subformats. I maintain all of these simultaneously because I need to be able to switch between different formats and subformats within a single document. And because I store many parameters in the tree, I don't want to have to fully define the complete list of parameters for every subformat. Instead, I take advantage of the `.search also` handler so that I request the parameter for a specific subformat and `\pgfkeys` will (assuming `.search also` has been setup properly) give the most specific customization that exists, falling back to the default setting if nothing else is specified.

For example, for the subformat 1 for format `test one`, I define the key

```
\pgfkeys(/stdt/.cd,
    test one/1/.search also={/stdt/test one,/stdt/default})
```

which has the result that if the key does not exist in that subformat, we first check the parent format, and then the default format for the key.

Then I use the following macro to retrieve the right parameter for the default context while still letting override things if I need to:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\stdtParameter} { O{\ActiveFormat} O{\theTestSection} m }
    {\pgfkeys{/stdt/#1/#2/.cd,#3}}
```

This works fine in ordinary contexts, but it's fragile and cannot be used when I need to expand first, for example if I want to use the parameter as an argument of `ifnumcomp` from `etoolbox`.

I'm able to use `\edef` if I invoke `\pgfkeysvalueof`, but not `\pgfkeys` itself. For example, this works:

```
\edef\temp{\pgfkeysvalueof{/stdt/\ActiveFormat/num columns}}%
\ifnumgreater{\temp}{1}{Do something}{Do something else}%
```

But I've been unable to do the same with `\pgfkeys`. All my experiments with `\edef` and variants have led to abject failure. The problem with using `\pgfkeysvalueof`, though, is that it sidesteps the `.search also` handler mechanism, and an undefined key will return `\relax`, which means that I would need to reimplement all the logic of `.search also` in my own macro, and I'm loath to do that if it's unnecessary.

How can I properly expand `\pgfkeys` so that I can write something like this?

```
\ifnumgreater{\stdtParameter{num columns}}{1}{Do something}{Do something else}
```

MWE to show the effects of different kinds of calls

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox,xparse}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\newcommand{\ActiveFormat}{default}
\newcounter{TestSection}

% We need to use cd before getting the parameter because giving the full path 
% will stop \pgfkeys from checking search-also trees.
\NewDocumentCommand{\stdtParameter} { O{\ActiveFormat} O{\theTestSection} m }
    {\pgfkeys{/stdt/#1/#2/.cd,#3}}

\pgfkeys{/stdt/.cd,
    format/.store in=\ActiveFormat,
    default/0/.search also={/stdt/default},
    default/1/.search also={/stdt/default},
    default/name/.initial=Default,
    default/my size/.initial=0.5in,
    default/my label/.initial=Generic Section,
    default/num columns/.initial={1},
    test one/.search also={/stdt/default},
    test one/name/.initial=Test One,
    test one/num columns/.initial={2},
    test one/my size/.initial=0.625in,
    test one/0/.search also={/stdt/test one,/stdt/default},
    test one/1/.search also={/stdt/test one,/stdt/default},
    test one/1/my label/.initial=Some Content,
    test two/.search also={/stdt/default},
    test two/name/.initial=Test Two,
    test two/0/.search also={/stdt/test two,/stdt/default},
    test two/1/.search also={/stdt/test two,/stdt/default},
    test two/my label/.initial=A Different Section
}

\begin{document}

Original format (should be default): \ActiveFormat

Testing \textsf{\textbackslash stdtParameter}

With no optional arguments, the default \textsf{my size} should be \pgfkeys{/stdt/default/my size}. 
I got a value of \stdtParameter{my size}.

With one optional argument, \textsf{test one/my size} should be \pgfkeys{/stdt/test one/my size}. 
I got a value of \stdtParameter[test one]{my size}.

Now ask for an explicit format which does not define a value for \textsf{my size}. I should get the default value above.
I got a value of \stdtParameter[test two]{my size}

With both optional arguments (format and section), the value of \textsf{test one/1/my label} should be `\pgfkeys{/stdt/test one/1/my label}'.
I got a value of `\stdtParameter[test one][1]{my label}'.

Now check for the fallback label when it's undefined. I asked for \textsf{test two/1/my label}. I should see 
`\pgfkeys{/stdt/test two/1/.cd,my label}'. 
I got a value of \stdtParameter[test two][1]{my label}.

By default we have \stdtParameter{num columns} columns.

% Switch active formats
\pgfkeys{/stdt/format=test one}

Switched active format to \ActiveFormat, but we're still in section \theTestSection.

The label is `\stdtParameter{my label}'.

\stepcounter{TestSection}

After incrementing the section counter, the label is now `\stdtParameter{my label}' and we
have \stdtParameter{num columns} columns.
% set columns for active format/subformat
\stdtParameter{num columns=3}

Now we have \stdtParameter{num columns} columns.

% The following won't work. We need to fully expand pdfkeys and pass that to \ifnumgreater
% \ifnumgreater{\stdParameter{num columns}}{1}{Multi-column action}{One-column action}

Checking full paths: Default = \pgfkeys{/stdt/default/num columns}.

Test one = \pgfkeys{/stdt/test one/num columns}

Test one, section one = \pgfkeys{/stdt/test one/1/.cd,num columns}

Test two, section one = \pgfkeys{/stdt/test two/1/.cd,num columns}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try using `/stdt/.is family` instead.  In the old documentation this was used to create a new "folder".

Comment: @John Kormylo Can you explain in more detail what you have in mind? I just tried the `.is family` methods, and the basic problem remains: I still can't get `\pgfkeys` to expand with `\edef`.

Comment: I am not an expert on using \pgfkeys, and what I learned now seems to be obsolete.  But I always used `/.is family` to create a new folder (so to speak) and `/.initial=...` to create a new entry.  Even `/.default` would fail without `/.initial`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/450260/how-to-expand-pgfkeys-value-when-the-key-path-contains-macros) gave me what I needed to solve this problem. Instead of trying to load the values directly from the key, I store them in intermediate macros. The solution below extends the linked answer to incorporate using `.style` to initialize all the values for a particular format type and `.search also`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox,xparse}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{parskip}
\newcommand{\ActiveFormat}{generic}
\newcommand{\ActiveDomain}{default}
\newcommand{\SectionName}{}
\newcommand{\numcols}{1}
\newcommand{\mysize}{0pt}
\raggedright

\pgfkeys{/stdt/.cd,
    format/.store in=\ActiveFormat,
    domain/.store in=\ActiveDomain,
    name/.store in=\SectionName,
    my-size/.store in=\mysize,
    num-columns/.store in=\numcols,
    % Generic defaults
    generic/default/.cd,
    .style={/stdt/generic/default/.cd,name,num-columns,my-size},
    name/.code=\pgfkeys{/stdt/name=Generic Format},
    num-columns/.code=\pgfkeys{/stdt/num-columns=1},
    my-size/.code=\pgfkeys{/stdt/my-size=18pt},
    % Format one defaults
    /stdt/format-one/default/.cd,
    .style={/stdt/format-one/default/.cd,name,num-columns,my-size},
    name/.code=\pgfkeys{/stdt/name=Format One},
    num-columns/.code=\pgfkeys{/stdt/num-columns=2},
    my-size/.code=\pgfkeys{/stdt/my-size=36pt},
    .search also={/stdt/generic/default},
    % Format one domain one
    /stdt/format-one/domain-one/.cd,
    .style={/stdt/format-one/domain-one/.cd,name,num-columns,my-size},
    name/.code=\pgfkeys{/stdt/name={Format One -- Domain One}},
    .search also={/stdt/format-one/default,/stdt/generic/default},
    % Format two defaults
    /stdt/format-two/default/.cd,
    .style={/stdt/format-two/default/.cd,name,num-columns,my-size},
    name/.code=\pgfkeys{/stdt/name=Format Two},
    num-columns/.code=\pgfkeys{/stdt/num-columns=3},
    .search also={/stdt/generic/default},
    % Format two domain one
    /stdt/format-two/domain-one/.cd,
    .style={/stdt/format-two/domain-one/.cd,name,num-columns,my-size},
    name/.code=\pgfkeys{/stdt/name={Format Two -- Domain One}},
    num-columns/.code=\pgfkeys{/stdt/num-columns=4},
   .search also={/stdt/format-two/default,/stdt/generic/default},
}

\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{/stdt/\ActiveFormat/\ActiveDomain}
\ifnumgreater{\numcols}{1}{\begin{multicols}{\numcols}}{}
    Values with \ActiveFormat/\ActiveDomain:

    Name: \SectionName

    Columns: \numcols

    My Size: \mysize
\ifnumgreater{\numcols}{1}{\end{multicols}}{}

\pgfkeys{/stdt/.cd,format=format-one,domain=default,\ActiveFormat/\ActiveDomain}
\ifnumgreater{\numcols}{1}{\begin{multicols}{\numcols}}{}
    Switched to \ActiveFormat/\ActiveDomain.

    Name: \SectionName

    Columns: \numcols

    My Size: \mysize
\ifnumgreater{\numcols}{1}{\end{multicols}}{}

\pgfkeys{/stdt/.cd,format=format-one,domain=domain-one,\ActiveFormat/\ActiveDomain}
\ifnumgreater{\numcols}{1}{\begin{multicols}{\numcols}}{}
    Switched to \ActiveFormat/\ActiveDomain.

    Name: \SectionName

    Columns: \numcols

    My Size: \mysize
\ifnumgreater{\numcols}{1}{\end{multicols}}{}

\pgfkeys{/stdt/.cd,format=format-two,domain=domain-one,\ActiveFormat/\ActiveDomain}
\ifnumgreater{\numcols}{1}{\begin{multicols}{\numcols}}{}
    Switched to \ActiveFormat/\ActiveDomain.

    Name: \SectionName

    Columns: \numcols

    My Size: \mysize
\ifnumgreater{\numcols}{1}{\end{multicols}}{}

\pgfkeys{/stdt/.cd,format=format-two,domain=default,\ActiveFormat/\ActiveDomain}
\ifnumgreater{\numcols}{1}{\begin{multicols}{\numcols}}{}
    Switched to \ActiveFormat/\ActiveDomain.

    Name: \SectionName

    Columns: \numcols

    My Size: \mysize
\ifnumgreater{\numcols}{1}{\end{multicols}}{}
\end{document}
```

Results:

[image: test getting values with and without explicit keys set]