# How to expand pgfkeys value when the key path contains macros?

Tags: expansion, pgfkeys

This question represents a second, more simplified, attempt at [a problem I asked about some time ago but for which I received no answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/406207/how-do-i-expand-pgfkeys-properly).

In short, I need to put the fully expanded result of a call to `\pgfkeys` in a macro for later use, and the key path itself contains macros. The purpose is that I have parameters which change depending on the type and part of the document one is in, and I want to have a single call to `\pgfkeys` (which will appear in the definitions of other macros/environments) automatically look up the right parameter for the currently active settings.

I tried using `.estore in`, but got the error `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]`.

Using `.store in` lets me set the key, but since the macro contains the unexpanded `\pgfkeys` function, I can't use it in a context like the argument to another macro/environment, and I haven't been able to figure out how to expand it before calling another macro. (In my various experiments with `\edef`, I usually wind up with unending compilation.) In the MWE, opening the `multicols` environment with the macro defined this way causes the error `!Missing number, treated as zero`.

So, how can get a fully expanded value into a macro set by `\pgfkeys` when the right side of the assignment is itself a call to `\pgfkeys`?

My preference is a solution that still lets me use `\pgfkeys` rather than `\pgfkeysvalueof` or some other key-value package, because I make heavy use of the `.search also` handler, but at this point I'm willing to consider other approaches, including `l3keys`, even if it requires a massive rewrite elsewhere.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newcommand{\ActiveFormat}{generic}
\newcommand{\ActiveDomain}{default}
\newcommand{\colnum}{1}

\pgfkeys{/stdt/.cd,
    num-columns/.store in=\colnum,
%   num-columns/.estore in=\colnum,
    generic/default/num-columns/.initial=2,
}

\begin{document}

\textbackslash colnum = \colnum

\pgfkeys{/stdt/num-columns=\pgfkeys{/stdt/\ActiveFormat/\ActiveDomain/num-columns}}

% This is fine with the .sore in version
\textbackslash colnum = \colnum

% There will be an error here
\begin{multicols}{\colnum}

Some text.

Some more text.

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I think you should use the `/stdt/generic/default` keys the same as how Ti*k*z uses its styles, to set other keys in the base directory (in this case `/stdt` instead of `/tikz`).

The following example results in:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newcommand\ActiveFormat{generic}
\newcommand\ActiveDomain{default}
\newcommand{\colnum}{1}

\pgfkeys{/stdt/.cd,
    num-columns/.store in=\colnum,
    generic/default/num-columns/.initial=2,
    generic/default/.code=\pgfkeys{/stdt/num-columns=2},
    generic/non-default/.code=\pgfkeys{/stdt/num-columns=4},
}

\begin{document}

\textbackslash colnum = \colnum

%\pgfkeys{/stdt/num-columns=\pgfkeys{/stdt/\ActiveFormat/\ActiveDomain/num-columns}}
\pgfkeys{/stdt/\ActiveFormat/\ActiveDomain}

% This is fine with the .store in version
\textbackslash colnum = \colnum

% No errors
\begin{multicols}{\colnum}

Some text.

Some more text.

\end{multicols}

\def\ActiveDomain{non-default}

\pgfkeys{/stdt/\ActiveFormat/\ActiveDomain}

\textbackslash colnum = \colnum

% No errors
\begin{multicols}{\colnum}

Some text.

Some more.

Some more.

Final column.

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```